# Is there a mechanism to change the default value for rich:calendar's "enableManualInput" attribute?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Currently the following code must be written for each date field using JBoss richfaces:

```
<rich:calendar value="#{dtl.rcvDt}" enableManualInput="true"/>
```

Is there a mechanism to set all instances of rich:calendar so that enableManualInput default's to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no easy way.

You can extend the calendar component (`HtmlCalendar`), provide a different default value in your subclass, and map it as your own component.

Comment: Thank you.  Wish we caught this accessibility requirement before so many screens were developed without this attribute being set.

Comment: @Brian - well, a simple search and replace wouldn't take much time